# Error while connecting to windows drive from linux machine [via java program]

Tags: java, smb, jcifs, libsmbclient

I am trying to connect to windows network drive using `Jcifs = 1.3.17` in java

code

```
String baseAddress = "smb://file-123/XYZ_Others/"
String DOMAIN = "XYZ"
smbFile = new SmbFile(baseAddress, new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(DOMAIN, userName, password))
//How i am using  smbFile
final boolean isDirectory = smbFile.isDirectory(); //getting error here
```

If i run the  code from mac it is working fine [it can able to connect] however if i try to run from linux [amazon cloud] i am getting following error

```
cifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect to server
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:882) ~[jcifs-1.3.17.jar:?]
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1335) ~[jcifs-1.3.17.jar:?]
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1417) ~[jcifs-1.3.17.jar:?]
        at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.isDirectory(SmbFile.java:1490) ~[jcifs-1.3.17.jar:?]
```

When i try to use smb client from command prompt

```
smbclient -L smb://test/ -U username -W ANT -R host -D DIR
```

Getting error as

```
Connection to smb: failed (Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME)
```

Comment: I guess your file server is not reachable from the internet...

Comment: Your Amazon cloud is connected to your server using VPN? If not it will not work because you are not in the same network.

Is the Mac located in the same network as the Server?

Comment: Hi, Thanks both yes, it is network related problem.Once we move the drive to same region as cloud desktop it starts to work fine. thanks

Comment: @JeyaKumar does your comment mean that the problem is resolved by having cloud machine in same region as network drive?

Comment: @Merlin : yes . for example my windows drive and cloud-desktop were in same region us-east-1